# Xamarin.Android Resource.ID error

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a little bit problem in my layout system. My Main layout contains a lot of sub layouts (ScrollView, HorizontalScrollViews, and in HorizontalScrollViews there are some LinearLayouts.) My problem is when I want to inicialize some ImageViews in my HorizontalScrollView, Visual Studio throws me an error (Resoure.Id does not contain a definition ...). Okay, I was like okay, let's test it with some other elements, and other elements in the same sub- layout are working correctly.(TextView, PlainText etc). What is the problem? In the Visual XML viewer, the IDs correctly appears, but In my MainActivity (after a SetContantView!) when i want to make a refference for them, i get an error. Can somebody help me? Thank you and sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all lines where you get the errors.

Clean your solution and rebuild it completely.

Then you will see your resource ids in main activity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot + sign while declaring id.Very common mistake

```
@+id/
```

instead of

```
@id/
```